# MySQL Query to MS Access Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ms-access

Hello I have been working with a project to MySQL database and I am converting it to MS ACCESS database.

Can someone help me for the equivalent of this query from MySQL to MS ACCESs SQL? 
Becouse my ms access query does not work.

The MySQL Query :

> Select  count(u.phone) as ordernr, u.firstname , u.lastname ,
>   u.address from user u join orders o on u.phone = o.phone group by
>   firstname ;

MS ACCESS Query (is not working)  which i tryed so far:

> Select  count(u.phone) as ordernr, u.firstname as firstname,
>   u.lastname as lastname , u.address as add from user u inner join orders
>   o on u.phone = o.phone group by firstname ;

is giving me this error message : *your query does not include the specified expression 'lastname' as part of an aggregate function*.

Looking forward for your help and/or suggestions! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct MS Access version is:

```
Select count(u.phone) as ordernr, u.firstname, u.lastname, u.address
from [user] as u inner join
     orders as o
     on u.phone = o.phone
group by u.firstname, u.lastname, u.address;
```

Note:

- `user` is a reserved word in MS Access.
- `join` operation needs to include the `inner`.
- `as` is needed for table aliases.
- The `group by` needs to include all columns (that is a SQL-thing true of all databases except MySQL).

Comment: @HasS . . . I just updated the answer.  I think I have all the access'isms accounted for.

Comment: Hmm it worked , thanks a lot for your help, i have many other queries that i want to convert and this helped a lot :) @Gordon Linoff

Comment: if you can help me on this one too , im getting a strange behaviour , and I think there is nothing wrong with this query : `Select i.itemname, i.id, i.price as pricexitem,oil.quantity , (oil.quantity * i.price) as price from orders as o inner join orderitemlist as oil on oil.orderid = o.id inner join item as i on i.id = oil.itemid where o.id= 2 ;`

Comment: Minor correction: Access SQL does not require the `AS` keyword for table aliases.

Comment: @GordThompson I have noticed that , but sometime it does and i dont know why :/  can you help me fix that query ?

Comment: @HasS - That is a different issue. Please [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Solved it alredy , the problem was with the Where clause..  the check should be maded in the end of query , not in inner join part :) @GordThompson

Answer (score 2):

You have to include in the `GROUP BY` clause every non-aggregated field present in the `SELECT` clause:

```
Select count(u.phone) as ordernr, 
       u.firstname as firstname, 
       u.lastname as lastname , 
       u.address as addr 
from user u 
inner join orders o on u.phone = o.phone
group by firstname, lastname, addr ;
```

Comment: Hello giorgos , thank you for your answer, the query you wrote is not working maybe becose 'user' is reserved from the ms access and it needs to be [user] but all the other parts of query is totally ok . Best regards