# SQL - aggregation with groupby and partitioning

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that looks like this called `sales`

```
 brand  | model    | sales           
--------+----------+------
 brand1 | model11  | 100
 brand1 | model11  | 300
 brand2 | model21  | 100
 brand2 | model22  | 400 
 brand3 | model31  | 100
```

I was using the following SQL query

```
SELECT 
     brand, SUM(sales)/SUM(sales) OVER () as sales_share
FROM sales
GROUP BY brand
```

So as to get the `sales_share` for each brand as below

```
 brand  | sales_share          
--------+--------------
 brand1 | 0.4
 brand2 | 0.5
 brand3 | 0.1
```

However, I was getting error `Attribute SALES.sales must be GROUPed or used in an aggregate function` - any pointers ?

Comment: SUM(sales)/SUM(sales) is 1, and remove over and ask exact question

Comment: @VISHMAY: `SUM(sales)/SUM(sales)`  indeed is 1, but `SUM(sales)/SUM(sales) OVER ()` is not

Comment: what is expected is not "SUM(sales)/SUM(sales)" but "SUM(sales)/SUM(sales) OVER ()" it is not the same and it isn't equal to 1. What is expected is (total sum for all brand)/(sum for one brand)

Answer (score 1):

The following works

```
SELECT 
     brand, SUM(sales)/SUM(SUM(sales)) OVER () as sales_share
FROM sales
GROUP BY brand
```

What was missing in the original attempt was the aggregation function - exactly like the error message said :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sql you should group by each attribute you select.  So your query would be something like :

```
SELECT 
     brand, SUM(sales)/SUM(sales) OVER () as sales_share
FROM sales
GROUP BY brand, sales
```

Comment: user3206440 is clearly using SQL as he/she is using Postgres. The part "if you are using sql" does not make sense.

Comment: Well , if he would use MySQL for example , all he needed was group by brand . But if he uses access he needs to include each attribute he selects .. I  said "If You are using SQL" because I once converted some Query from MySQL to Sql access and the problem was the group by clause.  This is  what i am talking about. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37775543/mysql-query-to-ms-access-query

@a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: The query is tagged with `postgresql` so why do you assume user3206440  might be using MySQL or even MS Access?

Comment: Didn't noticed , my bad

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
select  
     brand, SUM(sales)as brand_sales
into tmp
from sales 
group by brand

select  brand , 
        total_sales /(select SUM(b.sales) from sales b) as total_sales 
from tmp 

drop table tmp
```

Comment: The `tmp` table is totally unnecessary. Plus: `create table as .. select ..` is the preferred way to create a table based on a select statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
  select brand , sales_share/sum(sales_share) over () sales_share from (
    SELECT 
       brand, SUM(sales)  as sales_share
    FROM sales
       GROUP BY brand
    ) a
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a window function for this:

```
SELECT brand, 
       sum(sales) / (select sum(sales) from sales) as sales_share
FROM sales
GROUP BY brand;
```

Depending on the data type of `sales` you might need a cast to a decimal, otherwise Postgres will use integer division

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/548ad/1

Comment: Are those sub-selects a good practice from performance perspective ?

Comment: @user3206440: yes, why not? It will be run only once and doing the `sum(sales) over ()` is likely to have the same performance. You can always use `explain (analyze, verbose)` to verify that.

Comment: @user3206440: I think you are right ;) I tested this with 100.000 rows and your version is indeed a bit faster.